# Finding two trees with the same post- and preorder

Tags: binary-tree, preorder, postorder, search-tree

I am looking for two different search trees with at least 4 nodes. The trees don't have to have the general search tree attributes.

The postorder and preorder from tree A has to be the same as the post- and preorder of tree B.

I don't really understand how to do that so that both trees are not identical.

Grateful for any hints.

Comment: Show some code and explain where the code doesn't work.

Comment: This is a theoretical question. Nothing about code.

Comment: Then show some pseudocode. How would you search a tree to find two subtrees that have the same post- and pre-order? (Or presumably return `false` if no two such subtrees exist.)